# if statement is not identifying the condition stored in variable

Tags: javascript

I am having jsp page in which i am asking few multiple choice questions. So I am using radio buttons to display options.

Now I want to write a javascript function for putting mandatory check for all the fields.
My code look like this.

```
var lengh = document.getElementById("totalQues").value;
for(i=1;  i <= lengh; i++){
        var radioName= "radio"+i;
        var radioQues = document.getElementsByName(radioName);
        var concatS= "";
        for(j=0; j< radioQues.length; j++){
            concatS = concatS+"(radioQues["+j+"].checked == false)";
            concatS= concatS + " && ";
        }
        var sliced=  concatS.slice(0, concatS.lastIndexOf("&&"));
        if(sliced){
            msgid="Question "+i;
            id="radio"+i;
            check=false;
            break;
        }
        if(check==false){
            alert("kopkopok the break part");

        }
    }
```

The problem lies in

```
var sliced=  concatS.slice(0, concatS.lastIndexOf("&&"));
        if(sliced){
            msgid="Question "+i;
            id="radio"+i;
            check=false;
            break;
        }
```

My if statement is not identifying the condition which I have stored in sliced variable.
Please help....

Comment: `slice()` returns an array so `sliced` would never be `falsy`. Check against the `length` property of `sliced` if you want to check if it contains any values.

Comment: `string::slice()` returns a string, not an array. An empty string would indeed be falsy, but I think OP actually wants the truth of the expression in the string checked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to evaluate the string

```
"(radioQues[1].checked == false) && (radioQues[2].checked == false) ..."
```

and see if the condition described is true. Comparing the string itself to `false` won't do that. Better to simply check the buttons as you loop through them, looking for one that's checked. If none was found, show your alert:

```
var lengh = document.getElementById("totalQues").value;

for (i = 1; i <= lengh; i++) {
  var radioName = "radio" + i;
  var radioQues = document.getElementsByName(radioName);
  var any = false;

  for (j = 0; j < radioQues.length; j++) {
    if (radioQues[j].checked) {
      any = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!any) {
    msgid = "Question " + i;
    id = "radio" + i;
    alert("kopkopok the break part");
    break;
  }
}
```